# Submit "&" to Drupal 6 form using cURL?

Tags: curl

I'm using this code to create a node in Drupal 6:

```
curl -b cookies.txt -d \
    title="$(sed '1,/sblmtitle/d;/slpstitle/,$d' file.html)" \
    -d form_build_id=form-5312da71abefb3bf1f63f1f2b7cf9105 \
    -d form_token=f65aaefcf6f4b20c9a3d34f5af13ccaf \
    -d form_id=post_node_form -d op=Save http://www.site.com/node/add/post
```

The `file.html` contains:

```
spasi
sblmtitle
Some title here & there
slpstitle
```

Drupal creates a node with title `Some title here`. Drupal rejects the character `&`;

What can I do to make Drupal 6 accept `&`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ampersand has a special meaning in URLs. In order to pass an real ampersand in a URL you must encode it as `%26`. You can either make that change with an extra sed expression or just change it in your file.

Answer (score 1):

`&` is used for separating form fields, use the `--data-urlencode` option to encode `&` properly:

```
curl -b cookies.txt --data-urlencode \
    title="$(sed '1,/sblmtitle/d;/slpstitle/,$d' file.html)" \
    -d form_build_id=form-5312da71abefb3bf1f63f1f2b7cf9105 \
    -d form_token=f65aaefcf6f4b20c9a3d34f5af13ccaf \
    -d form_id=post_node_form -d op=Save http://www.site.com/node/add/post
```

From the [manual page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

> --data-urlencode 
> (HTTP) This posts data, similar to the other --data options with the exception that this performs URL-encoding. (Added in 7.18.0)
>
> > name=content
> > This will make curl URL-encode the content part and pass that on. Note that the name part is expected to be URL-encoded already.

Comment: interesting, but not works